# Ошибка в создании тасков asyncio python3.10

Tags: python, парсер, asyncio, aiohttp

Изучаю асинхронность в питоне. Очень сложная для меня тема. Есть такой код, который парсит магазин кроссовок и складывает данные в .json файл. В синхронном стиле все работает, но оооочень долго. Решил переписать, используя асинхронность, но банально не понимаю почему выдает исключение `RuntimeError: Task got bad yield:*адрес корутины в памяти*`.

```
import aiohttp
import json
from time import time

URL = 'https://xn--80awro.xn--p1ai/krossovki?start={position}&tmpl=component'
HEADERS = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0'
}

SHOP_URL = 'https://хасл.рф/'

all_trainers_data = {'trainers': []}


async def get_content(url: str, session: aiohttp.ClientSession) -> None:
    """Отвечает за отправку GET-запроса на страницу с данными"""
    print(f'Going to url {url}...')
    async with session.get(url=url, headers=HEADERS) as response:
        json_data = await response.json()
        await parse_json(json_data['rows'])


async def parse_json(data: dict) -> None:
    """Отвечает за парсинг данных формата json, складывает все в общий словарь с данными"""
    for iterator in range(0, 40):

        current_trainers_json = data[iterator]

        attrs = current_trainers_json['attributes'][0]['list']
        able_sizes = []

        for attr in attrs:
            able_sizes.append(attr['name'])

        trainers_info = {
            'name': current_trainers_json['name'],
            'actual_price': current_trainers_json['product_price'],
            'old_price': current_trainers_json['product_old_price'],
            'discount': current_trainers_json['product_old_price'] - current_trainers_json['product_price'],
            'image_url': current_trainers_json['image'],
            'link': SHOP_URL + current_trainers_json['product_link'],
            'able_size': able_sizes
        }

        all_trainers_data['trainers'].append(trainers_info)


def write_file(raw_trainers_data: dict) -> None:
    """Преобразует данные в объект json, а так же записывает их в .json файл"""
    with open('хасл_рф_кроссовки.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(raw_trainers_data, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)


async def main() -> None:
    """Формирует таски"""
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(get_content(URL.format(position=i), session) for i in range(0, 4080, 40))]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    write_file(all_trainers_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t0 = time()
    asyncio.run(main())
    print(f'{time() - t0} seconds has passed')
```

Comment: нужно было правильно расставить скобки. глупая ошибка. но почему то дальше скрип падает с ошибкой ```iohttp.client_exceptions.ContentTypeError: 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: text/html; charset=utf-8', url=URL(```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import asyncio
import json
from time import time
import aiohttp

URL = 'https://xn--80awro.xn--p1ai/krossovki?start={position}&tmpl=component'
HEADERS = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0'
}
SHOP_URL = 'https://хасл.рф/'



async def get_content(url: str, session: aiohttp.ClientSession) -> None:
    """Отвечает за отправку GET-запроса на страницу с данными"""
    async with session.get(url=url, headers=HEADERS) as response:
        try:
            json_data = json.loads(await response.text())
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            print(response)
            return
        print(f'Going to url {url}...')

    """Отвечает за парсинг данных формата json, складывает все в общий словарь с данными"""
    for trainers_json in json_data['rows']:
        trainers_info = {
            'name': trainers_json['name'],
            'actual_price': trainers_json['product_price'],
            'old_price': trainers_json['product_old_price'],
            'discount': trainers_json['product_old_price'] - trainers_json['product_price'],
            'image_url': trainers_json['image'],
            'link': SHOP_URL + trainers_json['product_link'],
            'able_size': [attr['name'] for attr in trainers_json['attributes'][0]['list']]
        }

        return trainers_info


def write_file(raw_trainers_data: dict) -> None:
    """Преобразует данные в объект json, а так же записывает их в .json файл"""
    with open('хасл_рф_кроссовки.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(raw_trainers_data, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)


async def main() -> None:
    """Формирует таски"""
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(get_content(URL.format(position=i), session)) for i in range(0, 4080, 40)]
        all_trainers_data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    write_file(all_trainers_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t0 = time()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
    print(f'{time() - t0} seconds has passed')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибку из комментария обойти можно так:

```
data = await resp.json(content_type=None)
```

На сервере не очень озадачились правильными заголовками:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.23.0
Date: Sat, 20 Aug 2022 09:09:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```