# Как извлечь json при парсинге?

Tags: python, парсер, asyncio, aiohttp

Хотел спарсить wildberries с помощью asyncio. Проблема в том, что когда использовал requests и извлекал json (requests.get(link).json()), всё было хорошо, json извлекался. Стал использовать asyncio и aiohttp. Всё делал по примеру с ютуба, но json не извлекается.
Ссылка на json c вайлдберриса:
https://catalog.wb.ru/catalog/pants/catalog?appType=1&couponsGeo=2,12,7,3,6,13,21&curr=rub&dest=-1113276,-77687,-398397,123585969&emp=0&kind=2&lang=ru&locale=ru&pricemarginCoeff=1.0&reg=1&regions=64,83,4,38,80,33,70,82,86,30,69,22,66,31,40,1,48&spp=23&subject=11;147;148;313;1695;2287;3835

Код:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import csv
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time


agent = UserAgent()
start_time = time.time()
all_data = list()


async def parse(session, page):
    url = f'https://catalog.wb.ru/catalog/pants/catalog?appType=1&couponsGeo=2,12,7,3,6,13,21&' \
          f'curr=rub&dest=-1113276,-77687,-398397,123585969&emp=0&kind=2&lang=ru&locale=ru&' \
          f'page={page}&pricemarginCoeff=1.0&reg=1&' \
          f'regions=64,83,4,38,80,33,70,82,86,30,69,22,66,31,40,1,48&' \
          f'sort=popular&spp=23&subject=11;147;148;313;1695;2287;3835'
    tasks = []
    async with session.get(url=url, headers={
        'user-agent': f'{agent.random}'
    }) as response:
        assert response.status == 200
        print(f'get page: {page}')
        response_text = await response.json()
        all_data.append(response_text)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


async def load_site_data():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for page in range(1, 16):
            task = asyncio.create_task(parse(session, page))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


def main():
    asyncio.run(load_site_data())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    end_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(f'Затраченное время: {end_time} секунд')
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью asyncio + aiohttp извлечь json

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1440991/470333

Comment: @СергейШ Спасибо, помогло